# how to find imageURL on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, url

how to find **image URL**  on **GitHub** so that I can add it on file for my information
basically I am working on open source so that and I want to push back my changes

Comment: What is image URL, what is your information?

Comment: means I want to add URL of my Image when we click on URL it opens our image

Comment: Where would you like to add it? To Readme file, or where?

Comment: I wanted to add it in .json file I have found the solution its right click>copy image address